# Icons not fitting in the width of Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a navbar in Bootstrap that includes icons on the right-side of the navbar. With this code the icons spill outside the navbar's width. How can i format the icons to be right-alligned but only as wide as the nav bar?

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
   </nav>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create a css as follows and add it to the container div

```css
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
   <div class="container nopadding">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        </ul></div>
   </nav>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4jm9nwc/1/)**

remove the class `container` in the div which is inside the `nav` element

also set a `margin-right:0px;` to your second `ul` which holds the icons.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="">  
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social" style="margin-right:0px;"> 
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
  </nav>
  </div>
```

View the above snippet in **Full Page Mode** to see the changes